# How to stop linux user even being able to see other user's directories

Tags: permissions, sftp

I'm building an sFTP solution but I can't stop group1user from seeing or more exactly listing group2user's directories. I've configured it so that group1user can't actually get into group2user's directories but they can actually see the directory name when they connect via FileZilla.

File structure =

```
             /upload/group1Directory

             /upload/group2Directory
```

dave is the owner and can see and enter both group1Directory and group2Directory

The current permissions look like this

```
rwxr-xr-x.   4 root root          46 Feb 17 09:55 upload

drwxr-x---. 2 dave group1     60 Feb 17 11:09   group1Directory
drwxr-x---. 2 dave group2     61 Feb 17 11:09   group2Directory
```

the sshd_config looks like this

```
Match User dave
        ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0002
        #PasswordAuthentication yes
        ChrootDirectory /upload
        PermitTunnel no
        AllowAgentForwarding yes
        AllowTcpForwarding yes
        X11Forwarding yes
        PubkeyAuthentication yes

Match User group1user
        ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0002
        #PasswordAuthentication yes
        ChrootDirectory /upload
        PermitTunnel no
        AllowAgentForwarding yes
        AllowTcpForwarding yes
        X11Forwarding yes
        PubkeyAuthentication yes

Match User group2user
        ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0002
        #PasswordAuthentication yes
        ChrootDirectory /upload
        PermitTunnel no
        AllowAgentForwarding yes
        AllowTcpForwarding yes
        X11Forwarding yes
        PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Any ideas how I can hide group2user's directory from group1user?...and vice-versa? Any help very gratefully received

Comment: Can't you just change the ChrootDirectory for group1user and group2user directly to their respective directories?
If you are able to do this, you might also want to remove r-x permissions for others on the /upload directory

Comment: hi thanks for getting back to me ..but I tried this and they couldn't connect at all when I tried that